# Function that is stored in Var and called in html

Tags: javascript, html

Wanted to create random code, store it in variable and show it in html.

```js
function GenerateButton() {
  document.getElementById("btn1id").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Txt").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = GFCode;
}

function randomString(length, chars) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
  return result;
}

function codeFunc() {
  document.write(randomString(4, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'));
  document.write("-");
  document.write(randomString(4, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'));
}
var GFCode = codeFunc;
```

```html
<div class="btn0" id="btn1id" onclick="GenerateButton()">Generate</div>
<div class="Txt" id="Txt" style="display=none;"> The Code is: <span id="code"></span></div>
```

If i do the document.write in the html document the code is generating, but i can't get it working from the js document.

Comment: Also don't use `document.write`. Just `return randomString(4, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') + "-" + randomString(4, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');`

Comment: Your title states "Function that is stored in Var...". Do you actually want to store the function in the variable? *Or* do you prefer to store the random code in the variable? ...as I provided in my answer. You can do either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question states: "...create random code, store it in variable and show it in html."

Don't use `document.write`. Simply return a string, assign it to a variable, and interpolate that variable in your HTML. To do so you'll need to execute `codeFunc()` which then assigns the returned random code (string) to `GFCode`:

```js
function GenerateButton(){
  document.getElementById("btn1id").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Txt").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = GFCode;
}

function randomString(length, chars) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
    result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
  }
  return result;
}

function codeFunc(){
  return ( // <-- return the code string
    randomString(4, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    + "-" 
    + randomString(4, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
  );
}
var GFCode = codeFunc(); // <-- execute codeFunc
```

```html
<div class="btn0" id="btn1id" onclick="GenerateButton()">Generate</div>
<div class="Txt" id="Txt" style="display=none;"> The Code is: <span id="code"></span></div>
```

---

If, as your *title* implies, you are intending to store the function in the variable, and not the random code produced by the function, you can:

```
...
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = GFCode(); // <-- execute function
...
var GFCode = codeFunc; // <-- assign function to variable
```

Either way, the random code needs to be returned from the function, and that function needs to be executed.

Comment: Yeah the first one worked for me, and i had an error in the code which didn't show me the code but i fixed it. Thanks anyway, i learned a lot from the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Since you set the GFCode variable to simply the function's name, you are setting it to the function itself, not it's return value. To actually run the function and get it's return value you must write it like this:

```
var GFCode = codeFunc();
```

Comment: Yeah but that way it shows my code at the top of the page when loaded, not in the <span> where i want it to be..

Comment: That is a problem with the codeFunc function, rewrite it so it returns a string with what you intend it to render to the page instead of writting the code to the document itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is returning null since you calling the variable before it get executed.

The function codeFunc() returns a function.

I change your code here.

```js
var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var GFCode =   `${randomString(4, chars)} - ${randomString(4, chars)}`;

function GenerateButton(){
document.getElementById("btn1id").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("Txt").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = GFCode;
}

function randomString(length, chars) {
var result = '';
for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
return result;
}
```

```css
.btn0 {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn0" id="btn1id" onclick="GenerateButton()">Generate</div>
<div class="Txt" id="Txt" style="display=none;"> The Code is: <span id="code"></span></div>
```

Comment: Your code works, but `codeFunc` does not return a function. It doesn't have a return statement, and therefore returns `undefined`.

Comment: I agree. It needs a return statement for the function to return something.  What I meant is the `codeFunc()` calls the whole function.